# dart's latest js-interop library causes some issues lately

Tags: javascript, dart

I have seen some strange changes in the latest js-interop library and I wonder if anybody can give some clarification about it.

After upgrading to the latest version I noticed dart2js doesn't work anymore. After some investigation I concluded the cause was an @proxy annotation inside the js-interop library ( also mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14540)).

Because of this I switched between a couple of versions and I noticed some functions like scoped have been deprecated in a timespan of only a couple of days after which it has been completely removed! If you missed the in between version in which this function is marked as deprecated you miss the hint which give's some info about it. Also note that the main tutorials about the js library on dartlang.org don't even give a hint about the fact that large parts of it have become outdated.

I decided to go back to version 0.0.26 and although it seemed to work as before... I noticed in one instance when retrieving a variable from the javascript context in dart I received a dart DateTime object and not a js.Proxy object.

Going back a version earlier (v0.0.25) I got back my js.Proxy when using a variable from the js context, as expected.

The weird thing is that on [github](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop) the versions go until 0.0.25 (which work as expected) and the one on [pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) has 3 versions more, which all break backwards compatibility a lot (which sometimes is needed) without clear instructions about what is going on (which I find lightly frustrating).

Can somebody give some clarifications about what is going on and what I can expect for the coming times?

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this breaking changes have been announced in [Future breaking changes in package:js](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/svfRZnfcTLM) and [BREAKING CHANGE: package:js deprecated features removed](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/PLhOusQlEuc).

Basically, starting from 0.0.26, [package:js](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) is now baked with [dart:js](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_js.html). This change comes with several things :

- scopes/retain/release are no longer needed
- several types are now transfered directly between Dart and Js and not proxied

  - `null`, `bool`, `num`, `String`, `DateTime`
  - `Blob`
  - `KeyRange`
  - `ImageData`
  - `TypedData`, including its subclasses like `Int32List`, but not `ByteBuffer`
  - `Node`
- Element from shadow dom can now be transfered as well
- `Callback` are now longer needed.
- **a really big performance improvement**

Here's a quick migration guide :

- scopes : remove `js.retain`, `js.release` and `js.scoped`.
- replace `new Callback.xxxx(f)` with `f` and remove `callback.dispose()`.
- replace `Proxy` with transferable type based on the above list.

Comment: I was only aware of the https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/announce so that is why i missed it. Thanks for clearing it up

Comment: Sorry for the pain @jdv145, I tried to land the changes in an order that would minimize pain, and allow you to pin to a version that allowed you to migrate incrementally if needed. I assumed that being able to choose a version in pub would make the short time-frame bearable.